# KMix shows non-functional sound card as default, no apparent way to change it

Tags: kde, kde-4, system-sounds, kmix

How do I change KMix's default sound card? I have "prefered" the correct one in Phonon (KDE's sound and video card configuration tool), I have selected it as the Master channel in KMix, what else can I try?

The screen shot is showing the two cards, the second one is the correct one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!! I just figured it out! I launched Phonon, went to the tab Audio Hardware Setup, and selected Internal Audio from the Sound Card dropdown menu, then I clicked Apply, and now it works!!